# Placing a point inside a convex polygon

Tags: polygon, point, triangulation

I want to place a point inside a convex polygon. Is the position that maximizes the minimum angle of each triangle unique?

I'm not very familiar with computational geometry, but I feel like this should be unique.

---

The problem is illustrated as follows.
[image]

Comment: @BERA I have added a draw.

Comment: @LYOmega Do you want to calculate the location of such a point for a random convex polygon? Or do you want to prove that it is a unique location? Be more specific about what you want.

Comment: @ComradeChe I want to know whether such location is unique. Is there a unique solution to this optimization problem?

Comment: If you want a proof you might be better off asking in [math.se].

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I appreciate your attention.